# Chrome 21.0.1180.83m - where is devtools.js located?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

I want to perform a hack on devtools.js to expand all of the DOM elements by default.  I read in another post on here that this was possible.

However, I can't find devtools.js, or for that matter, the Application folder that supposedly exists at C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome.  I've tried this both on my Windows 7 laptop and my Windows XP desktop (different path for the desktop, obviously) and the folder doesn't even exist...which leads me to believe it's somewhere else and named something else.  I'm showing hidden folders on both machines, so that's not it, either.  I even searched both computers...no devtools.js file on either one.

Where would I look for the devtools.js file?

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be packed in a file called `resources.pak`. The package seems to contain a lot of other (binary) files as well, so I'm not sure if you're going to have much luck editing it.

Answer (score 0):

Might be a bit late to the party but i was searching for a very comparable question i had and found some answers, so i thought i'd share my findings.

It seems that the devTools.js and also the other files for the DevTools front-end are packaged inside the browser.
So there is no file on your hard-drive named devTools.js, there is an option to get the source for the Developer Tools and use it as a stand alone front-end though.

On this page i found some instructions as to how you would go about using your own front-end.
http://dev.chromium.org/devtools

Good luck!
PM5544